# Windows option is showing in grub but windows is not booting

Tags: dual-boot

I have installed Windows and Ubuntu on two separate hard drives.
Grub menu is also showing options to boot Ubuntu and windows. Ubuntu is booting normally but when I choose to boot windows following error occurs.

error : no such device : AE9A-24B8.
error : disk 'hd1,gp2' not found.

Note : When I try to boot windows directly by changing boot priority windows boots successfully.

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows, but that also means Windows cannot need chkdsk nor be hibernated. And fast start up in Windows sets the hibernation flag. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: I have already turned off hibernation and fast start up in windows.

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair